# Heroku Python Scrapy firefox error

Tags: python, macos, firefox, heroku, scrapy

hey guys i tried to deploy my scrapy project onto Heroku and everything was deployed. But when i try to execute heroku run scrapy crawl crawlername i get the error

RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox. i have added these lines to /etc/paths.

```
/Applications
/Applications/Firefox.app
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

After adding them to etc/paths i am able to run firefox from the terminal by just typing firefox and firefox will open. But when i try to rerun heroku run scrapy crawl crawlername i get the same error.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

thats inside my scrapy script to open the web browser.

if im in the same directory that i have created the heroku app and i run scrapy crawl crawlername everything works fine and i get my results but when i try to do heroku run scrapy crawl crawlername i get the error regarding firefox shown above. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Looks like Firefox isn't installed

Comment: what do you mean? i have firefox what more i must do to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As heinst mentions Firefox isn't installed on **Heroku**. This means that you have to have Heroku not on your local machine but on the Heroku instance which is running your script.

The lines you've added to `/etc/paths` are of your Mac -- not the Heroku instance you are trying to run your application on.

Alternatively try to use something like [this buildpack](https://github.com/bensomers/firefox-buildpack). This requires some additional tools like Xvbf to have your Firefox an in-memory buffer to let Selenium click the right buttons and so on.

Alternatively: why not using Scrapy without Selenium? Most of the tasks can be done without any browser-interaction but you have to search of course a bit more to find your solution.